# Libstreaming - use VLC as a RTSP client (1080P resolution)

Tags: streaming, rtsp, rtsp-client, libstreaming

I'm trying to use VLC as a RTSP client.The rtsp server is based on the **libstreaming** example1. I'm use Samsung Galaxy S6.
Is it possible to stream **1080p** resolution? Then what is the rtsp URL format.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, use `MediaRecorder` instead of `MediaCodec`.
Max resolution for `MediaCodec` is 640x480.
**libstreaming**:

```
public static final byte MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API = 0x01;
```

Comment: Do we just need to uncomment
mSession.getVideoTrack().setStreamingMethod(MediaStream.MODE_MEDIACODEC_API); line to enable mediacoder API? Is there anything else needed?

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim hard to say, i didn't see your code. In general yes, you should set `MODE_MEDIARECORDER_API` as StreamingMethod. I used `libstreaming`, but override a lot of their code for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

1080p works for me on Meizu MX4, but has huge latency and sometimes mpeg artifacts.
I tested this on many devices and it depends on device model.
URL format does not depend on video resolution
to set resolution use .setVideoQuality() method as described in readme here https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming